# array length - loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have these values:

```
$x[0][0] = 1;
$x[0][1] = 2;
$x[0][2] = 3;

$x[1][0] = 4;
$x[1][1] = 5;
$x[1][2] = 6;

$x[2][0] = 7;
$x[2][1] = 8;
$x[2][2] = 9;
```

Now, i need to make an autonomous array. Basically, it will change with the dimension. For example a 4*4 and not a 3*3.

```
    $arr= array(
    0=>array($x[0][0],$x[0][1],$x[0][2]), 
    1=>array($x[1][0],$x[1][1],$x[1][2]), 
    2=>array($x[2][0],$x[2][1],$x[2][2])
    )
```

I am trying a for loop, but without success.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x[0][0] = 1;
$x[0][1] = 2;
$x[0][2] = 3;

$x[1][0] = 4;
$x[1][1] = 5;
$x[1][2] = 6;

$x[2][0] = 7;
$x[2][1] = 8;
$x[2][2] = 9;

$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        $arr[$i][$j] = $x[$i][$j];

    }   
}

print_r($arr);
```

If I understand you correctly

Answer (score 0):

You mean nested loop ?
like (sample values ) :

```
$ar = array();
for( $i =0 ;$i<5;$i++)
{
  for($j=0;$j<5;$j++)
  {
     $ar[$i][$j] = 0 ;
  }

}
```

Comment: sorry i mean $ar[$i][$j] = 0 ;